# Passing value of Input text field into Session Variable

Tags: php, forms, session, isset

I used method GET to get the value inside the input text field.

```
<?php 
echo "<form method='GET'>"; 
echo "<input type='text' placeholder='0' name='valueinputed' value ='$value'?>";
echo '<a href="mycart.php?valueinput='.$idsecure.'">Submit </a>';
echo "</form>";
?>
```

where when the submit clicked it will get the product id and its session variable.

and go page mycart

```
if(isset($_GET['valueinput'])){
$valueinputed = $_GET['valueinputed'];
$_SESSION['cart_'.(int)$_GET['valueinput']] = $valueinputed;

header('location:'.$page);
```

}

This code is setting input text field and set the session variable.
I used this code to show to you what I mean and I want to do. 
I also used post method but it resulted me to delete the entire session variable(specifically).

Anyway, my variable for quantity of product is `$value`
and for each this way

thank you for reading this, I really appreciate any help.

Comment: `$_GET['valueinput']` vs `$_GET['valueinputed']`.Err, wait. My fault. You need a submit button in your form to submit the form, not an `<a href>`

Comment: I already tried it a while ago, but when the page refreshed. It comeback to its value. Anyway how to you put like <a href="page.php?valueinput= bla blah.in button?

Comment: and one more thing. It affects all session variables so I stopped using it tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<a href="mycart.php?valueinput='.$idsecure.'">Submit </a>` doesn't submit the form, it just links to the page in the `href`.

Change your form to

```
<?php 
echo "<form method='GET' action='mycart.php'>"; 
echo "<input type='hidden' name='valueinput' value='$idsecure'>";
echo "<input type='text' placeholder='0' name='valueinputed' value='$value'>";
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit">';
echo "</form>";
?>
```

to submit the form with all of its fields to `mycart.php`, where you can then access `$_GET['valueinputed']`.

Comment: I used a href to get the value of session variables. Like for example to get the id of a product.But ill try it.

Comment: : Undefined index: valueinput . It gives me this error.

Comment: My fault, forgot about that GET parameter. I added a hidden field with the value, please try again

Comment: your idea made my codes worked! I used type  hidden to set the value of a product id thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using `valueinput` and `valueinputed` which might not be intended.

Furthermore, you may need to call `session_start();` before accessing `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Yes, I have it already. I didnt include it in this post because its naturally put session start in using session variable. But thanku for reminding me